# Avoid step into AsyncTaskBuilder

Tags: c#, asynchronous, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging

I have a lot of asynchronous code and some of it is in nuget libraries so I have to disable "Enable Just My Code".

This means on every `await` if I step into the code I hit the AsyncTaskBuilder (Shift F11 to step out) and then into the awaiter (Shift F11 to step out) before I land on the "interesting" code - these gets very tedious with 20 async calls!

Is there any way of saying I'm not interested in debugging system code whilst still retaining the ability to step into packaged library code?
[image]

Comment: Maybe you can try go Debug menu=>options: 

1.uncheck `Enable .net framework source stepping`

2.uncheck `Enable source server support`

3.In debugging=>symbols=>uncheck Microsoft Symbol servers.

Comment: Both are already unchecked, I've amended the question with the current settings.

Comment: Hi Paul, sorry for the delay. It's hard for me to reproduce same issue: `hit AsyncTaskBuilder.`.Could you share some sample code? Also you can uncheck the Source link support and Symbol server restart vs to check if it helps. But i have to say the setting that indicates we're not interested in source code with `enable just my code` is not available as i know:(

Comment: I'll put together a little gist and post the url here

Comment: Any update for this issue? I'm trying to get some suggestion from one engineer who's more experienced in this topic, it may take some time.